# Reordering XML Nodes and Elements

Tags: c#-4.0, linq-to-xml

Workign on xml reorder
My XML is as follows:

```
 <Subjects>
   <Subject>
     <Name></Name>
     <Height></Height>
     <Addresss>
        <Address>
           <City>AB</City>
        </Address>
     </Addresses>
   </Subject>
   <Subject>
     <Name></Name>
     <Height></Height>
     <Addresss>
        <Address>
           <City>CD</City>
        </Address>
     </Addresses>
   </Subject>
 </Subjects>
```

Now i want to creat XML as follows by adding address reference to the subject

```
<Order>
 <Subjects>
   <Subject>
     <Name></Name>
     <Height></Height>
     <Address ref="A1"/>
   </Subject>
   <Subject>
     <Name></Name>
     <Height></Height> 
     <Address ref="A2"/>      
   </Subject>
 </Subjects>
 <Addresss>
     <Address id="A1">
        <City>AB</City>
      </Address>      
      <Address id="A2">
        <City>AB</City>
      </Address>
  </Addresses>
</Order>
```

I am using below code to do this

> ```
> var index     = 0;
> var output    = new XmlDocument();
> var order     = output.AppendChild(output.CreateElement("Order"    ));
> var subjects  = order .AppendChild(output.CreateElement("Subjects" ));
> var addresses = order .AppendChild(output.CreateElement("Addresses"));
> foreach (XmlElement subject in input.SelectNodes("/Subjects/Subject"))
> {
>   index++;
>     var address = (XmlElement)subject.RemoveChild(subject.SelectSingleNode  ("Addresses"));
>      address = (XmlElement)address.FirstChild;   // Addresses to Address
>      address.SetAttribute("id", index.ToString());
>      var newAddress = (XmlElement)subject.AppendChild(input.CreateElement("Address"));
>      newAddress.SetAttribute("ref", index.ToString());
>      subjects .AppendChild(output.ImportNode(subject, true));
>      addresses.AppendChild(output.ImportNode(address, true));
>      }
>     output.Save(Console.Out);
>    Console.ReadLine();
> ```

I created these xml using XElement syntax so to implement this forcing to parse to XmlDocument.
How to do the same in Xml LINQ ?

Comment: I think it'd be easier to apply an XSLT (Stylesheet) than to use LINQ for this scenario.

Comment: please share me the example if you have any.